# How to align text with an image

Tags: css, html

I can't seem to be able to align my text properly. I want to align it next to a certain image (near the bottom).

So I started by doing `bottom: 0` but it just aligns it near the top. There is another text near the top, and it seems to only adjust near that.
https://jsfiddle.net/xo1sje8m/

```css
.H01 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="H01">HELLLO EVERY1</h2>
```

Not sure what is going wrong. Here is a screenshot of where it aligns:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: it is working in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xo1sje8m/)..

Comment: You need to provide more HTML and CSS if we are to see the issue with your code

Comment: Please add your code in the question itself. The jsFiddle code requirement is there for a reason.

Comment: It is horizontally aligned to center, are you trying to vertically align to center it as well?

Comment: If you want to align it with, "our rad slogan neat", in the photo, both divides need to be centered and have the same margins/paddings etc. Include the html and css for "our rad slogan neat" to see why or what is different with it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xo1sje8m/1/ there is all my code.

Comment: I want to align it next to an image near the bottom of the page. it is called clock.png.png. But when I try to align it vertically, it just stays at the top. That is my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to position the image, use this to move it a certain distance from the element above it

```
margin-top: 200px;
```

Using vertical-align on the image just tells the nearby text where to align according to the image.